# My app makes a query every second but sometimes the query takes more than a second

Tags: node.js

I'm currently making a small nodejs app to monitor the player count on a game server. Here is my app.js

```
    var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var query = require('game-server-query');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

function ping(callback) {
    query({
        type: 'arma3',
        host: 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
      },
      function(state) {
        var num = state.raw.numplayers;
        callback(num);
      }
    );
  }

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  ping(function(num) {
    res.render('index.ejs', {
      count: num
    });
  });
});


io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('_pask', function () {
    ping(function(num) {
      socket.emit('_prefresh', num);
    });
  });
});

server.listen(8080);
```

and here is my client file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Data</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Players:
    <%= count %>
  </p>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

    socket.on('_prefresh', function(num) {
      console.log(num);
    });

    setInterval(function() {
      socket.emit('_pask');
    }, 3000);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

so basically, sometimes, the request takes more than a second so the app crashes with "Cannot read property 'numplayers' of undefined", I assume it means that the program tries to read the integer and that it cannot read it because the query isn't finished yet.
So, can anyone of you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that `state` is coming as `undefined` from backend for some reason, add a check for `state`.

```
function ping(callback) {
    query({
        type: 'arma3',
        host: 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
      },
      function(state) {
        if(state !== undefined){
          var num = state.raw.numplayers;
          callback(num);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That fixed the problem! In my case, because of some weird thing with the protocol of the plugin, we need to check if state.raw is undefined, not state

Answer (score 0):

On your server code, only do the emit IF the value is set.

Fire the emit every second using settimeout

```
setTimeout(function() {

   if (value!=null) {
       socket.emit HERE
   } else {
       console.log("not emitting coz value not set");
   }

}, 1000);
```